# Interdependece of parameters in Machine Learning problems

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say we have 10-D data from class of students. The data involves parameters like *Name*, *Grades*, *Courses*, *No. of hours of lectures*, etc. of all the students of the class. Now, we want to analyze the impact of *No. of hours of lectures* on *Grades*. 
If we closely watch our parameters, *Name* of the student has nothing to do with *Grades*, but *Courses* taken by student "might" have impact on *Grades*.

So, there could be parameters which are dependent on each other while some others can be totally independent. My question is, how do we decide that which parameter has impact on our classification/regression problem and which don't?

PS: I am not looking for exact solutions. If someone can just show me the right direction or keywords for google search, that should be sufficient. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you're looking for is called [dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction). The Stanford [machine learning class](http://www.ml-class.org/course/video/preview_list) goes over one method ([principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)).

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of [independent component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis). ICA a family of methods for finding the statistically independent components of data sets. This is a difficult problem, and there exists a large variety of algorithms for finding good solutions. A popular algorithm is [FastICA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastICA).

There are also related concepts of [whitening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation) and [decorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorrelation).